# Java using loop, accept five integers, input from console and return the min & max

Tags: java, loops, console, max, min

I am trying to create a Java code using a loop that will accept five integers input from console and return the smallest and the largest.  I am having a problem with the code coming together.Thank you

```
import java.util.*;
public class Highest_LowestofFiveIntegers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter five integers separated by a 
          space i.e. 2 6 55 1 3 910: "); 
    int number = 0;

    number = input.nextInt(); 
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x<5; x++){ 


        if (x == 0 || number > max){ 
        max = number;  
        }               
        if (x == 0 || number < min){ 
        min = number;  
        }               
     }                 
         System.out.println("Highest value: " + max);
         System.out.println("Lowest value: " + min);

}
```

}

Comment: What kind of object is input? Should not input sentence be inside the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Put `number = input.nextInt();` **in** the `for` loop; **not** before it.

```
int max = 0, min = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) { 
    int number = input.nextInt();
    if (x == 0 || number > max){ 
        max = number;  
    }               
    if (x == 0 || number < min){ 
        min = number;  
    }               
}   
System.out.println("Highest value: " + max);
System.out.println("Lowest value: " + min);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I moved it.  However it still gives me a error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Duplicate local variable number
 input cannot be resolved

 at HIghest_LowestofFiveIntegers.main(HIghest_LowestofFiveIntegers.java:15)

Comment: Do you have a `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` somewhere? If not, add it (before the loop).

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that.  Added but still   errors on the int number - input.nextInt()  Duplicate local variable number

Comment: @AlinaPolishchuk Remove all `int number` statements **before** the loop.

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch that worked, awesome!  So that error was just telling me that there were two int number statement?